# How to find the intervals on an integral with upper bound of x?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem. The upper bound of $x$ is throwing me off. I do know, the FTC should be applied -- here is the problem.

Consider the function: 
$$\int_{1}^{x}\ (t^2-4t-5)\,dt$$

1. Find the intervals on which $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing.
2. Find the intervals on which $f(x)$ is concave up or concave down.
3. Use the above information to sketch the graph of $ y = f(x)$.

Initial attempt:

$$F(x) = \frac{1}{3}(x)^3 - 2(x)^2 - \frac{5}{2}(x)^2$$

$$F(1) = \frac{1}{3}(1)^3 - 2(1)^2 - \frac{5}{2}(1)^2 = -\frac{25}{6}$$

$$F(x) = F(a)-F(b)$$

$$F(b) = F(a)+F(x)$$

$$F(b) = -\frac{25}{6} + F(x) $$

So, this is where I'm stuck for finding $F(b)$. Also, for (1) and (2), typically for previous problems I would take the first derivative to find the increasing/decreasing and the second to find the concave up/down. How am I suppose to get there from this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute derivative using Leibnitz formula:
$$f'(x) = x^2 - 4x - 5 = (x-5)(x+1)$$

Now you can find where this is positive or negative. From here you calculate $f''$ for concavity, and also integrate $f'(x)$ to get $f(x)$

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} - 2x^2 -5x + C$$

Now $C$ can be found using the fact that $f(1) = 0$

Comment: thanks! One question, where are you getting $f(1) = 0$ ?

Comment: @craz1001 $\int_{1}^{1}g\left(x\right){\rm d}x=0$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to find $F\left(x\right)$ in order to solve the question, so the answer of @samjoe is right and concise. Nevertheless, if you insist on calculation the integral then I'll expand here. You have a **definite** integral, so you need to do the integration and substitute the limits

$$F\left(x\right)=\int_{1}^{x}\left(t^{2}-4t-5\right){\rm d}t=\left[\frac{t^{3}}{3}-2t^{2}-5t\right]_{1}^{x}=$$

$$=\left(\frac{x^{3}}{3}-2x^{2}-5x\right)-\left(\frac{1^{3}}{3}-2\cdot1^{2}-5\cdot1\right)=\frac{x^{3}}{3}-2x^{2}-5x+\frac{20}{3}$$

Comment: I blindly applied leibniz :)

Comment: @samjoe You're correct. Though, the OP seems to be confused while carrying the unnecessary integration, so I think my answer also helps in a way.

Comment: Obviously it is helpful, rather more direct.

Comment: I guess it wasn't asking to compute the definite integral, but this is very helpful nonetheless -- thanks!